# After adding intent filers for firebase dynamic link support app does not listed in app list in android devices

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm implemented firebase dynamic links in flutter app at first in android manifiest file has intent filter like below & app is listed in device app list ,

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

but after adding below intent filters to support firebase dynamic links app not showing in app list

```
<intent-filter>

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data
                        android:host="redbull.page.link"
                        android:scheme="https"/>

            </intent-filter>
```

Am I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two intent filters rather than nesting both details in one. So for example:

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    
        <data
        android:host="redbull.page.link"
        android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

FYI Dynamic Links service will shut down soon so using in new projects is not advised https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq

Comment: Can you please suggest a better option in replace of dynamic link